# req.files does not exist while sending form data in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am tying to store a form data along with files. when I am use form without this `enctype="multipart/form-data"` works fine but req.files dosent exist in req which i need to upload files. and when i use enctype in form, still req.files dosent exist and req.body does not have any data.
I was trying to implement multer to handle files but req.files dosent exist so didnt get any idea. 
my route

```
const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true});
router.post('/save_file', urlencodedParser, home.add_file);
```

my controller

```
exports.add_file = function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.files);
}
```

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Do you do `router.use(urlencodedParser)` before `router.post`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**bodyParser**, the library you use to parse your request from the server, doesn't parse files, you need to use another library, (**multer** is very good and easy). 
So first :

1. Install Multer: npm install multer --save
2. Here the link of Multer: https://github.com/expressjs/multer
3. Use this example as base:

```js
let multer = require("multer"); //the library
let storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'path/to/upload/your/file');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
});//Configure the place you will upload your file

let upload = multer({ storage: storage }); //instanciation of multer
// image is the name of the input in the form
router.post('/your_endpoint', upload("image"), (req, res)=> {
  let file = req.file; //contains the file
  let path = file.path; //contains the paths
})
```

Comment: My first answer on stackoverflow, :).

Comment: yes it works, but in this code upload("image") was showing error that upload is not a function. So, i added upload.array("image") coz i am uploading multiple files. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using multer in your node app -

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer[enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)